# Unable to pull data from API in python

Tags: python, json, api, data-extraction

My code is below. I am trying to pull data from the [COVID-19 API](https://covid19api.com/) and want to store it in a dataframe to view it and then later use it for analytics purpose in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/us"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Works fine. Of course, this returns a reference to the `json` method. Use `r.json()` to get the actual json content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to *call* the `json()` method:

```py
print(r.json())
#           ^^
```

Right now you're getting a reference to the method itself.

Comment: IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Comment: I want to store the result into data frame, How can I do that ? any clue? tried with multiple read operations of pandas but was unable to do.

Comment: How are you trying to do that now? Your error message and the code you shared don't match up, but simply replacing `r.json` with `r.json()` should do the trick.

Comment: import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/us"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())

Comment: @RohanDesai, that won't generate the `ValueError` you mention in your question, and it doesn't even attempt to create a dataframe. Please don't try to share code in comments. It's very hard to read, as you can see. Instead, edit your question.

Comment: Hi @chris, I want to first view the data and based on it I want to insert it into df. Ideally I should be able to view it right? I tried the error message with other threads and tried that as well, that didnt worked.

Comment: @RohanDesai, my point is that you can do whatever you want with the JSON. Your problem is that you weren't _calling the method_. If you want to create a dataframe, go nuts: `df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())`. But there are unlimited ways to proceed, so without _you_ sharing more about what _you_ are trying to do (ideally by adding more code to your question) we can't help you further.